# Make a neder to forbid from oneself reward in the World to Come

Tags: sources-mekorot, halacha-theory, reward-punishment, nedarim-shevuot, maharal

I always understood that a *neder* is forbidding physical pleasure or benefit from oneself. I believe this is the common understanding. However, I saw a surprising statement of the Maharal in his Tiferes Yisroel Chapter 6.

> שאמרו במקומות הרבה 'מצות התורה לאו ליהנות נתנו', אלא בשביל גזירות נתנו...והטעם בכולם, מפני שמצות התורה לא נתנו ליהנות, רק לעול על האדם. ואל תאמר כי פירוש 'לאו ליהנות' בעולם הזה, רק לטוב לנו לעולם הבא. דאם היה תחלת נתינת המצוה לישראל להטיב להם בעולם הבא, אם כן מצות ליהנות נתנו.
>
> They said in many places '*mitzvos* were not given for pleasure/benefit'. Rather, they were given as decrees...the reason for all these instances is because the Torah wasn't given for pleasure, rather just as a yoke on a person. And don't tell me that 'not for pleasure/benefit' is meant for in *this* world, but [the Torah] was given for good in the next world. For if the whole point of giving the *mitzvos* to the Jews was for their benefit in the World to Come, then *mitzvos* ***were*** given for pleasure/benefit.

If I understood his words properly, he's saying that had the purpose of the Torah and *mitzvos* been to give us reward in the World to Come, that would be called הנאה, pleasure/benefit. If so, I would infer that a *neder* would be effective.

Consequently, I'm wondering if the natural consequence of this would be (according to him), that one could make a *neder*, forbidding oneself from benefitting from the reward in the World to Come? Is this is a correct conclusion? Does anyone discuss this possibility (with or without mentioning the Maharal). I do admit I'm not sure how this would play out practically.

---

<sup>In case someone wants to say the reward is לא בא לעולם, I would respond that according to the Nefesh HaChaim 1:12, the reward one creates with their *mitzvos* *is* בעולם, but we just don't have access to it yet.</sup>

Comment: I asked a prominent posek in E"Y if one could write in the front of his sefer that if a person choses to use the sefer that they forgo any of the schar limud Torah that they would recieve. He responded that no one would really have gmiras da'as to do such a thing (to give up his schar limud Torah). Do with this information what you will.

Comment: If one can give up his portion for someone else (https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/70979/giving-away-olam-haba-to-save-someones-life) or sell it (https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/5152317/jewish/The-Man-Who-Sold-His-Place-In-Heaven.htm) then why wouldn’t he be able to make a neder on it?

Comment: Is it בידו?....

Comment: He is saying that mitzvos are not for hanaah, ever. So your question isn't relevant to the Maharal.

Comment: No sources, so just writing this as a comment, but... I think we have to distinguish between two kinds of answer to "what mitzvos are for". One can discuss their purpose, why did Hashem command them. Or one can discuss our motive, why should we be obeying them. The answer to the first question is quite likely approximated by "Hashem commanded mitzvos because it is the nature of Good to be of benefit to others". But we shouldn't be doing mitzvos for the sake of that benefit...

Comment: ... Like in a good marriage. Both work for (1) what's best for the other and (2) what's best family they're building. This means that the husband's answer to "why did you?" shouldn't be identical to the wife's. Even though it all coheres in a single goal.

Comment: I don't think it's possible. Hana'ah in the world to come is a direct consequence of the state of the soul experiencing it. Neder or no neder, I don't think it's avoidable. Might as well make a neder while still alive not to obey the law of gravity. I think it would qualify as "shav".

Comment: @N.T. read it again, he's saying they weren't *given* for hanaah. Read the whole piece.

Comment: @MichaBerger `Hashem commanded mitzvos because it is the nature of Good to be of benefit to others` the Maharal in that chapter rejects that.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: I still don't see why your question is specific to Maharal.

Comment: @N.T. because a neder is usually understood to forbid **physical** pleasure. The Maharal clearly disagrees.

Comment: @robev, where? The Maharal says it's not about hana'ah, but where does he say that it isn't about hatavah? I was under the impression that he agrees with the broad array (as hashkafically wide a spectrum as from R Saadia Gaon to the Ramchal) that EVERYTHING Hashem does is about hatavah. It's only when you get to the later Aristotilians (maybe the Rambam, but again, not R Saadia, R Bachya ibn Pequda or Ibn Geveirol) that you get rishonim who argue that even that is an overly specific claim about the Unknowable One.

Comment: That's a sugya in Rosh Hashanah. Rav Yehuda against Rava.

Comment: @MichaBerger I'm referring to what he writes in that Chapter: `אין הפירוש שהוא יתברך צוה המצות בשביל להטיב לנו, שאין זה כך. רק הוא יתברך צוה עלינו כמלך הגוזר, רק שהגזירה הזאת היא לטוב לנו לחיותנו כיום הזה אם נקיים המצות, ולא שתחלת הגזירה הוא לטוב לנו. `

Comment: @robev, I sit corrected. Although it does confirm my pigeonholing the Maharal as a non-Mequbal mystic.